# Jboss Wildfly resteasy upgrade

Tags: jboss, upgrade, wildfly, resteasy

I've googled to find detailed working tutorial for update Jboss Wildfly resteasy to latest version (3.0.17) but seems without solutions.

I'm testing on wildfly 10.0.0.Final release-version: "2.0.10.Final" 
with resteasy core version. First question how to list (from shell or from Gui) all core modules version in use?

From official documentation i'm using jboss-jaxrs-api_2.0_spec-1.0.0.Final version but i want use for my project resteasy 3.0.17

I can accept globally upgrade and/or instruction to use resteasy 3.0.17 only in my war project "bypassing" core wildfly resteasy implementation.

I read [official Jboss Resteasy upgrade](http://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/3.0.17.Final/userguide/html/Installation_Configuration.html#upgrading-wildfly) but without success.

Is there some guide or complete tutorial about manage modules on jboss wildfly ?

Or someone has already had these headaches and can share suggestions ?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this post from JBoss forum:

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/274219

Basically from Wildfly 11 it will be possible to see the module versions on console and in regards to the upgrade, it's manual work.